# How do I apply the modulo such that an index is never 0?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, modulo

Suppose I index the days of the week starting with 1 as Monday and 7 as Sunday. I have four arrays x, y, z and r which store variables for each day of the week. For example, x[1] is the amount of revenue earned on Monday, y[7] is the amount of revenue carried over from Sunday and z[6] is the amount of revenue saved from Saturday.
The total revenue on Monday is x[1] + y[7] + z[6] = r[1]. Similarly, the total revenue on Tuesday is x[2] + y[1] + z[6] = r[2].

I am trying to write a for loop something like this:

```
for i in 1:7
    x[i] + y[i-1] + z[i-2] = d[i]
end
```

Where when i = 1 and i = 2, the indexing does not become less than or equal to 0 (my indexing starts at 1 and if the result is 0 I get an out of bounds error).

I tried using the modulo function to assist with this, but I realize I am getting 0 in some cases, no matter what values I try. For example, adding 7 and then applying modulo 7 ensures that z[i-2] is z[6] when i = 1, but gives y[i-1] = y[0] when i = 1:

```
for i in 1:7
        x[(i+7)%7] + y[(i-1+7)%7] + z[(i-2+7)%7] = d[(i+7)%7]
end
```

Is there an efficient solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add 6 instead of 7 inside the modulo and add one outside.

`( i + 6 ) % 7 + 1`

Comment: But when i = 1 wouldn't it give (1 + 7) % 7 + 1 = 8 % 7 + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2?

Comment: Start with 0-based indexing. What language are you using with 1-based indexing?

Comment: I am using Julia and unfortunately I can't use another programming language. Would starting the for loop at 0 work?

Comment: So add 6 instead of 7 inside the modulo. That gives you a 0-based index + 7 that will always map to a legal 0-based index in your array. Still add 1 after to get to your 1-based index.